# sort Numpy array elements by value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an NxN array of values, and I want to sort these values by binning them, and for each bin, return a copy of the original with only the corresponding values remaining and all others replaced by zero. For example, if I have:

```
x = np.array([[1.1,2.2],[1.2,3.2]])
bins = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

Then I want:

```
output = [[[1.1,0.0],[1.2,0.0]],[[0.0,2.2],[0.0,0.0]],[[0.0,0.0],[0.0,3.2]]]
```

What I have so far:

```
Z = np.shape(x)[0]
Y = np.shape(x)[1]
X = np.shape(bins)[0]-1
output = np.broadcast_to(x, (X,Y,Z))
```

This creates an array which contains a copy of the original for each bin. Then I figure I would use np.where to set all but the correct values to 0.0, but my mind blanks when I try to think about how exactly to write it, and I'm not sure it's the best way in particular either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: By binning, you would like to keep all 1.x together, 2.x together and so on? 
Otherwise, I don't get why the second group and the third are not merged ?

Comment: Yes that's right, so in this case the bins would be [1,2,3,4], I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit dirty but you can try this

```
outputs = np.zeros(((len(bins)-1,) + x.shape))

for bin_idx, (inf, sup) in enumerate(zip(bins[:-1:1], bins[1::1])):
    outputs[bin_idx][np.where(np.logical_and(x>inf, x<sup))] = x[np.where(np.logical_and(x>inf, x<sup))]
```

Comment: It seems to work, like you said I am inclined to think there's a cleaner answer but I think I can at least use this for the time being.